# GUI adapter for old DOS application

Tags: user-interface, adapter, dos

I have an old DOS application which accepts some files as input, does some calculations and saves results into file system. This app uses terminal as sort of GUI, where you can choose input files, types of calculations to perform and choose where to save the result. I don't know the logics behind calculations and am not able to reuse them in a new project.
The problem is that the users of this app want a modern looking GUI which will be easier to work with.
That is why, I have an idea to create an adapter which will translate button clicks into commands in DOS and grab text output to show in modern GUI.
Is it possible and where should I start from?

Comment: What you need to do is research the logics behind the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. How to start from depends on your programming Tools. If you use a RAD tool like Delphi or Lazarus or Visual Besic or ... then make your GUI design first and define Events after. For a Button click it is ButtonXClick(); In the RAD tool you will find a object inspector with properties and ther values and Events and their values. Go to Events page there, look for onClick-event. Double click there in the value line and you will get an empty Event handler, wehre you can write your Code for your application.

If you dont have or use such RAD tool, take a GUI Framework for DOS. Create your frontend and write your Code which is to call in Dependance of your button clicks.